# mysql SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS problem with join

Tags: mysql

Why this query returning 0 rows?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.*, b.id AS key1, b.name AS catname 
FROM #__cd_ads a
LEFT JOIN #__cd_categories b ON a.type = b.id
```

when removed  b.id AS key1, b.name AS catname than works.

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Comment: sql_calc_found_rows is pointless unless you're using a limit clause.